# PHP caching - out of the box

Tags: php, caching

I have an application wherein I want to cache parsed pages and DB results. I know about APC (depends on PECL), PEAR and other options like memcached. But all of these require installation of additional frameworks and/or packages.

Is there a way I can use (memory) caching out of the box? Is there something like .Net's Application object where I can store shared data for all users?

Comment: What's your reason for wanting caching? Is your PHP site performing slowly or are you just trying to get any and all optimisations happening on your code?

Comment: Nope no slowness so far - MySQL does a great job when optimized nicely. But I have a template parser that generates pages on the fly from HTML templates - parsing placeholders and everything. I just want to have an optimized way of handling that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far a I know, there is no default caching mechanism in PHP similar to .NET's application object. The only thing that comes close is storing things in the `$_SESSION` object, but that would mean caching per user and not global caching.

Comment: Yes, I came across that solution as well. But since my application has some public pages that are same for all users, it wouldn't be much effective I guess.

Comment: @Sayak I'm afraid not. From what I've heard most people go with memcached for adding caching to their PHP sites.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll go with a filesystem approach I think, just for the templates.

Comment: That is what I did. For many purposes, the filesystem approach is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "No".

If you're adverse to installing APC/Memcache, your best approach would be to store them in an already shared location such as the filesystem or MySQL.

Comment: I guess I'm better off writing my own filesystem based caching. I'll not cache the DB stuff - no point as MySQL would do that in the memory anyway. I'll probably just cache the template files - I am reading the HTML template each time from the filesystem anyway - I suppose reading the parsed version from a cache file would be more efficient.